# Paint happening midway through PaintComponent

Tags: java, synchronization, paintcomponent

Sorry if this is too specific. I had a real tough time trying to articulate my searches and am scratching my head at this point. I decided enough is enough, and to post in case someone can help me.

So the first image below shows the issue that I am having and the second is what it looks like most of the time.  I am getting incorrect painting sometimes where the top layer and bottom layer of my game are not in sync.  The reason I iterate all of the tiles twice is because I need to paint different things at different layers.  On a somewhat side note: I am wondering if there are any improvements to speed such as using double buffered.

[image: badpaint]
[image: goodpaint]

My paintComponent code is quite long as there is a lot to paint, but I am not sure why it would attempt a repaint mid way through(before DrawTopMap() is called).  Unless I am missing something else that is what I assume the problem to be.

A sampling of the times:

```
time: 17
time: 17
time: 19
time: 17
time: 18
time: 18
time: 19
time: 18
time: 17
time: 18
```

Most of the time this is fairly consistent which is great.  Any help would be tremendously appreciated.  Thanks so much for your time!!

```
//bits and pieces to keep this short
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.trace("begin: REPAINTNG...");
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    final Composite freshComp = g2.getComposite();

    //map
    DrawMap();
    g2.drawImage(gamePanelImage, 0, 0, null);

    //enemy: players
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : playersHashTable.entrySet()) {
    ...
    g2.drawImage(SpriteSheetCutter.makeColorTransparent((BufferedImage) SpriteStore.get().getSprite(GetSpriteString(tempRace, tempGender)).getImage()), ((((MyClient.xTiles-1)*32)/2) - ((MyClient.characterX - tempX)*32)), ((((MyClient.yTiles-1)*32)/2) - ((MyClient.characterY - tempY)*32)), null);
    ...
    }

    //mobs
    //npcs

    //player
    g2.drawImage(SpriteSheetCutter.makeColorTransparent((BufferedImage) SpriteStore.get().getSprite(GetSpriteString(MyClient.characterRace, MyClient.characterGender)).getImage()), ((MyClient.xTiles-1)*32)/2, ((MyClient.yTiles-1)*32)/2, null);

    //above tiles
    DrawTopMap();
    g2.drawImage(gameTopPanelImage, 0, 0, null);

    g2.dispose();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time: " + (endTime - startTime));
}

private void DrawMap() {
    int count = (MyClient.characterX - (MyClient.xTiles/2)) + ((MyClient.characterY - (MyClient.yTiles/2)) * MyClient.mapWidth); //top left map tile
    for (int x = 0; x < MyClient.xTiles; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < MyClient.yTiles; y++){
            if (count > -1){
                if (!MyClient.groundLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("res/images/tiles/" + MyClient.groundLayer[count] + ".png").draw(gamePanelImage, x * 32, y * 32);
                }
                if (!MyClient.buildingLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("res/images/tiles/" + MyClient.buildingLayer[count] + ".png").draw(gamePanelImage, x * 32, y * 32);
                }
                if (!MyClient.objectLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("res/images/tiles/" + MyClient.objectLayer[count] + ".png").draw(gamePanelImage, x * 32, y * 32);
                }
            }
            count += MyClient.mapWidth;
        }
        count -= MyClient.yTiles * MyClient.mapWidth;
        count++;
    }
}

private void DrawTopMap() {
    gameTopPanelImage = new BufferedImage(32 * MyClient.xTiles, 32 * MyClient.yTiles, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //to prevent streaks
    int count = (MyClient.characterX - (MyClient.xTiles/2)) + ((MyClient.characterY - (MyClient.yTiles/2)) * MyClient.mapWidth);
    for (int x = 0; x < MyClient.xTiles; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < MyClient.yTiles; y++){
            if (count > -1){
                if (!MyClient.topLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("res/images/tiles/" + MyClient.topLayer[count] + ".png").draw(gameTopPanelImage, x * 32, y * 32);
                }
            }
            count += MyClient.mapWidth;
        }
        count -= MyClient.yTiles * MyClient.mapWidth;
        count++;
    }
}
```

@MadProgrammer... when I move(or something else does) my server returns a message.  My Client then updates all of those hashmaps and then calls repaint:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyClient.gamePanel.repaint();
    }
});
```

***EDIT***

I have figgured out my issue but I have not the slightest idea how to solve it.  My Client is mid painting sometimes, when my client thread that listens for the server's messages updates the location of the player.  See the race condition (I think its called) here in the log.

```
20203 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - begin: PAINT...
20203 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - begin: REPAINTNG...
20203 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - Map drawing started.
13,21 //sign
20207 [Timer-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.client.MyClient  - promage@walkNorthWest
20207 [commandReceiver-promage] INFO com.jayavon.game.client.MyCommandReceiver  - promage-walkNorthWest@true|62,44
20212 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - Map drawing done.
20217 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - Map top drawing started.
14,22 //sign overlay
20217 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - Map top drawing done.
20222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.jayavon.game.graphics.MapGamePanel  - end: REPAINTNG...
```

As you can see it drew the sign on the map, then the server told the player its move was valid, then it changed the players coords, then it drew the overlay, and repaint finished.  Do I need to synchronize?  I have never been good at that(clearly), can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Unless you are calling paintComponent manually, it is unlikely that it is been called more the once per paint cycle, as the actual painting is controlled by the Event Dispatching Thread. In theory, it should be impossible for the paintComponent method to paint called again while it's already been executed. It's possible that you're modifying the underlying model by which the paintComponent is using to paint content, but it's impossible to know without more context

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your help, even though someone downvoted it.  I appreciate the help so much.  I added some more explanation above that will hopefully allow you to guide me better.  I call repaint() every time my data changes.  Please let me know if this helps or if you were looking for something else to better help me understand.

Comment: Do you synchronize `playersHashTable`? @JayAvon

Comment: @Thomas thanks for confirming my suspicion.  I honestly have never had to use it before because on my server I use concurrentHashMaps.  I am going to have some reading ahead of me :) I found http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html.  If there is anything else you can think of for reading/examples please let me know.  Thanks so much!!!